# Is it possible to import an entire game (from exe-file) to a new Unity Project?

Tags: import, unity-game-engine

Let's say I have a game that is already built with Unity. I do not have its source-code, only the exe-file is present. Now, I need to add some new features on top of it. Is it possible to import the existing game to a new Unity project, e.g. by adding it to an empry GameObject?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What modifications do you want to make? To which game?

Comment: Actually, it's not a game. It's a research simulation. I want to add Gesture Recognition to that simulation. However, the gestures do not have to interact with the original simulation itself. Gestures only modify general Screen settings, such as rotation of the screen, or zooming into certain areas of the screen.

Comment: In which case you may be able to achieve what you want by spoofing those actions. Of course, it would probably be easier to just edit the base unity project.

Answer (score 1):

Without the source, no it is not.

Additionally you may not have a good legal standpoint unless you have express permission to modify the game (in which case you could simply ask the developer for access to the source), or the license is suitably open.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Don't have to worry about license issues (I am the owner...). I know, it might seem curious for you why I want to import it as an exe-file... For what I am doing right now, it might be nicer to have two seperate programs, where the first one is imported by the second one. Anyways, it's just an idea I just had (a "nice to have").

Comment: I'm still not certain what you aim to achieve. If you want to enable modding in your game, then you could simply load resources at runtime, if you want an overlay of some kind, you could put that in the base game.